# change date format DD-MON-YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to change date format which I received reading from excel cell file is "30-mar-2016" to 03/30/2016. I have tried below

```
     String inputDate = "30-mar-2016";
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
     Date startDate;
     startDate = df.parse(inputDate);
```

It gave me- java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "30-mar-2016"
   .
I also tried below code

```
     String inputDate = "30-mar-2016";
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
     String startDate;
     startDate = df.format(inputDate);
```

getting   -- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Can anyone help me  .

Comment: Look at the argument you're passing to `SimpleDateFormat`. That doesn't match the format of the string you're parsing. As for your format version - you need to parse the original string into a `Date` first, *then* format it. Basically, you need two `SimpleDateFormat` objects, one with the input format and one with the output format.

Comment: Parse using format `dd-MMM-yyyy`. And read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) carefully, esp. chapter "**Date and Time Patterns**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input string `30-mar-2016` is in the format `dd-MMM-yyyy`. Your output format is `MM/dd/yyyy`. So you need two `DateForamt`s. One for parsing original input string, one for formatting output string.

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); // for parsing input
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  // for formatting output
String inputDate = "30-mar-2016";
Date d = df1.parse(inputDate);
String outputDate = df2.format(d); // => "03/30/2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved using below

```
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
     Date date = sdf.parse("30-mar-2016");
     sdf.applyPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
     System.out.println(sdf.format(date));//got 03/30/2016
```

Thanks everyone for your quick response